# In Xamarin Forms Application how to get focus to non interactive elements like Labels and Images when using TalkBack in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, accessibility, swipe, talkback

In Xamarin Forms application, when i turn on TalkBack/Screen Reader for Accessibility in Android and swipe through the screen the screen reader doesn't read text on screen like label's and other images, It only reads interactive elements like buttons. How to make the talk back read the label content on swipe.

Comment: take a look at Xamarin's guide for using accessibility with Xam.Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/accessibility/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree to true for that label or other non interactive element.

`<Label Text="My label. It speaks a story. The story is real" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True"/>`

U can add custom extra detail for that label that Talkback will read loud.

`<Label Text="My label. It speaks a story. The story is real" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True" AutomationProperties.HelpText="This label describes that"/>`

see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties) for detail

Comment: Hi Eragon and Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code properly? You can read here on [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), thanks!